# Codeigniter submit not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Error**
Submit button from the view does not pass the value.

After submit button is clicked, then pass value from view to controller, then to the model. Database structure consists of table(booking) and column name ( booked_id, name and mobile) . But the value is not passed to the controller neither to the database.

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($post)?$post->name:''; ?>" name="manakamana[name]"/>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($post)?$post->mobile:''; ?>" name="manakamana[mobile]"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">POST</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function bookManakamana(){

    if ($data = $this->input->post('manakamana')) {
        $data['created_on'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->booking->add($data);
        redirect('booking');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
function add($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('booking', $data);
}
```

Comment: you have not given the form action

Comment: `if ($data = $this->input->post('manakamana'))` to `if (($data = $this->input->post('manakamana')))` also `var_dump($this->input->post('manakamana'))` and tell us the output...

Comment: @Vicky no action means post on same method... :)

Comment: I would look in using the form helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: @wolfgang1983 honestly good idea ! this made my life easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form action is not given

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'controller name/function name' ?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($post)?$post->name:''; ?>" name="name"/>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($post)?$post->mobile:''; ?>" name="mobile"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">POST</button>
```

in controller

```
public function bookManakamana(){
if ($this->input->post('name')) {
    $data['created_on'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
    $data['mobile'] = $this->input->post('mobile');
    $this->booking_models->add($data); //booking_model is the name of model
    redirect('booking');
} else {
    $this->load->view('index');
}}
```

Comment: who will put php tags in action for you ??